# How to pass data from object into new array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, file-upload, vuejs3

I want to send only one of the fields contained in the data object var arrImg. The first thing I want to push is an image field of var arrImg with a condition where checked is true into the new array image on crudData:{'image':[]}. Then the second I want to push the field name of var arrImg with a condition where checked is true into a new array name on crudData:{'name':[]}. Checked value is set to false first, but will change to true when the input checkbox is clicked. Does someone understand for the case I'm asking? i'm new to javascript. Thanks.

Here's myfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Annisa_Lianda30/d0ber5Lu/24/

This is my code:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            crudData:{
                'id': null,
                'name': [],
                'image': [],
                'arrImage': [],
            },
        }
    },

    imageUpload(e, maxItem){                    
            let input = this.$refs.uploadImage
            let file = input.files
            if(file.length > (maxItem - this.crudData.arrImage.length)){
                $('#uploadMultiFile').val('')
                alert('You can only upload max '+maxItem+' items')
            } else {
                for(let i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
                    var valueArr = this.crudData.arrImage.map(function(item){ return item.fileName })
                    var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
                        return item == file[i].name 
                    })
                    if (isDuplicate) {
                        alert("You've already uploaded this file")
                        continue
                    }else{
                        var arrImg = {
                            blob: URL.createObjectURL(file[i]),
                            image: file[i],
                            fileName: file[i].name,
                            checked: false,
                            name : null
                        }
                        this.crudData.arrImage.push(arrImg)
                        console.log(this.crudData.arrImage)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        uploadImage(e){
            this.$refs.uploadImage.click()
        },
        removeImage(key){
            this.crudData.arrImage.splice(key, 1)
        }, 

}
```

This is the output i got from crudData.arrImage:
[Output Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JevIk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Hopefully this code snippet can help guide you towards what your looking for.

```
let checkedImages = this.crudData.arrImage.filter(img => img.checked)
let imageFiles = checkedImages.map(img => img.image)
let names = checkedImages.map(img => img.fileName)
console.log({ imageFiles,names })
```

Comment: Hello, can you give me a clue more specific? because when i add this, i just get Array(0)length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0) when i look at console log.

Comment: At the bottom of your function imageUploaded(e, maxItem){...}, place this code and then run console.log({ imageFiles,names }).

Comment: can you check my code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Annisa_Lianda30/d0ber5Lu/3/ ?

Comment: Happily. Looking at it now.

Comment: What i mean is i want to push 2 data from arrImg object. First the image field and checked with the condition true (where the condition is true after the checkbox is clicked) which is in the arrImg var to be pushed to crudData{'image':[]}. then secondly field name and checked with condition true (where condition is true after checkbox is clicked) which is in var arrImg to be pushed to crudData:{'name':[]}

Comment: I added a button to log data after uploading images. This is similar to when user would go to submit. The log method filters the arrImages where checked and maps props to seperate arrays, https://jsfiddle.net/npa1xd2r/

Comment: Can the filtered data array images and names be returned to the section in crudData:{} instead of creating a new data{} like that? because when i try to return in part contained in crudData{} it doesn't work at all, no data is output when console log.

Comment: Of course it can. I created two new props[] on crudData, imageFiles/names. I then changed the log() method to set to these props: https://jsfiddle.net/pk04fg7h/2. Does this solve your question? If so please click the check next to my answer so I get the sweet repuation points :)

Comment: I don't understand when I update and try to move the code in the log into the propertyImageUpload method, the console log doesn't output any data. Because what I want the process to do is inside the propertyImageUpload method.  https://jsfiddle.net/Annisa_Lianda30/d0ber5Lu/22/

Comment: Think about it for a second. It's the same reason I added a log button to the fiddle. What is the checked value for each image, when the imageUpload() gets called? Look at the console.logs here: https://jsfiddle.net/odw9s81n/1/